# why are my expired memberships showing as current?

Tags: civimember

can't give any other details than looking at my memberships, I see every single membership is showing as current despite we are LONG past the date when the memberships expired.

All memberships were imported from a csv.

Answer (score 2):

Is your cron running and is in the scheduled jobs "Update Membership Statuses" enabled?

If both are active what is in the "View Job Log" of "Update Membership Statuses"?

You can also run "Update Membership Statuses" manually once to see if this will solve your problem.

Comment: looking at /civicrm/admin/job?reset=1 it looks like it is not.  However, I don't believe that I have my cron running properly, because I have yet to manage to get my scheduled emails to send properly either.